# Error in my Google Sheets Importrange/Query code

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to import a few columns of code when it meets a certain criteria (it is for a member of staff called Jan) from my Master Checklist. The column I want exporting are columns A-F. My code keeps coming up with errors:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE('Master Checklist'!,A3:F100,"select A3:F100 where G matches 'Jan'"))
```

My code keeps coming up with an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything is in the same spreadsheet:

```
=QUERY('Master Checklist'!A3:G,"select A,B,C,D,E,F where G matches 'Jan'")
```

[importrange()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) is dedicated to external spreadsheet and you have to mention the id in this case

If you import value from another spreadsheet

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("id or url","'Master Checklist'!A3:G"),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 where Col7 matches 'Jan'")
```

Note that

- you do not need to mention the url, the id is sufficient
- A,B,C ... becomes Col1,Col2,Col3 ...

Comment: That code is 100% spot on, I really appreciate your help with that, thank you.

Comment: To apply this same code but exporting to external spreadsheet, would the following work:?
=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet-URL",A3:G,"select A,B,C,D,E,F where G matches 'Jan'")

Comment: Not exactly, I have updated my answer

Comment: Once again, that works perfectly. You have really helped me here - thank you!